# How can I show a table of the data that I see on console?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dropdown

I'm building an app where someone can select an option from two drop-down lists. Selecting the first shows the second and after the second the user can see some data. I can see the data at the console but I can't show them in a table at my page. Can I use something like ngx-datatable?

```js
showInfo(value) {
       
    let selectedPro = this.diadikasies.find(diad => diad.id == value);
    this.diadikasies = selectedPro.content;
    console.log(selectedPro);
  
    }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="diadikasies && diadikasies.length > 0" class="form-group">  
  <label for="diadikasies">
    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Διαθέσιμες Διαδικασίες: </label> 
  <select #proc 
  (change)="showInfo(proc.value)">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected>Επιλέξτε Διαδικασία</option>
  <option *ngFor="let diad of diadikasies" [value]="diad.id">{{ diad.title.rendered }}</option>      
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is what you want.

#### Next time show more code.

- what you have
- what you want
- console.log() output

#### On you .ts file lets assume you have this data for 2 selects

```
const dataForSelect_1: any = [
  {name: 'option 1, value: 'val_1'},
  {name: 'option 1, value: 'val_1'}
]

const dataForSelect_2: any = [
  {name: 'option 1, value: 'val_1'},
  {name: 'option 1, value: 'val_1'}
]
```

#### on you .html file lets say you have this code

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of dataForSelect_1" [value]="food.value">
        {{option.value}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field [hidden]="!form.get('dataForSelect_1').value.length > 0">
    <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of dataForSelect_2" [value]="food.value">
        {{option.value}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

</form>

<table *ngIf="data">data</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div *ngIf="selectedProcess">
  <h4>{{ selectedProcess.info1 }}</h4>
  <h5 *ngIf="selectedProcess.info2">INFO</h5>
</div>
```

so simple after all...